# Grails - GORM generating wrong query syntax

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Hi I having a `Hibernate domain` like

```
class Parent {
    ....
    @javax.persistence.OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = {javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch(org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    private java.util.Set<Child> childs;
    ...
}

class Child {
    ...
    @javax.persistence.ManyToOne
    @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;
    ...
}
```

And trying to write `gorm` query like

```
def criteria = Parent.createCriteria();
List result = criteria.list() {
   //fetchMode "childs", FetchMode.JOIN
   childs {
       eq("childProperty",testValue)
   }
}
```

I could able to get the expected result, but in background the `sql` is like

```
select this_....... from parent this_
inner join child child_ on this_.parent_id = child_.parent_id
left outer join child child_ on this_.parent_id = child_.parent_id // this line is buggy
where child_.childProperty = (?)
```

My concern is the second `left outer join` which not actually need to yeild the result.